# Functional statement in Python to return the sum of certain lists in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I'm trying to return the count of the total number of elements contained in all sublists with a length > 1 contained in a parent list:

```
x = [[4], [6, 4, 9], [4, 6], [0], []]

# 1) Filter on x for only lists whose length is > 1
# 2) Reduce the new list to a sum of the lengths of each sublist
# result should be 5
```

This is what I have tried:

```
# Invalid as y is a list
reduce((lambda x, y: len(x) + y), filter((lambda x: len(x) > 1), x))
```

I think a map might be involved somehow, but I'm not sure how to structure it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanted a functional approach `filter` `sum` and `map` would do the job:

```
In [10]: x = [[4], [6, 4, 9], [4, 6], [0], []]

In [11]: sum(map(len, filter(lambda s: len(s) > 1, x)))
Out[11]: 5
```

Comment: `filter(lambda s: len(s) > 1, x)` can be `filter(None, x)` since we know OP's list only contains lists.

Comment: @gill, that would remove empty lists not lists that have 1 or less elements.

Answer (score 5):

Why you just don't use a [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within `sum()`?

```
>>> x = [[4], [6, 4, 9], [4, 6], [0], []]
>>> 
>>> sum(len(i) for i in x if len(i)>1)
5
```

Read this article about the fate of `reduce()` in Python 3000 by Guido van van Rossum. http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

And if you are looking for a functional way as a logical approach you can just use `map()` and `sum()` and still without `reduce()` and `filter()` :-)

```
>>> x = [[4], [6, 4, 9], [4, 6], [0], []]
>>> 
>>> sum(map(lambda i:bool(i and i.pop(0) and i)+len(i), x))
5
```

Answer (score 4):

You had a good start, but you made it much more complicated than it needed to be.

You can just sum a generator.

```
sum(len(y) for y in x if len(y) > 1)
```

Comment: Ahh, didn't know that an if clause could be added like that. I've used it for `return 'this' if (something) else 'that'`, but didn't know it could work in other contexts. Thanks

Comment: @BrianHVB Yup. You can do that in any type of generator/comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with other answers that your attempt was complicated and there could be simple solution for your question, But I would like to guide you in your attempt. You were close, a little modification in your attempt -

```
x = [[4], [6, 4, 9], [4, 6], [0], []]
reduce(lambda x,y: (len(x) + len(y)) if isinstance(x, list) else (x + len(y)), filter((lambda x: len(x) > 1), x))
# result would be 5
```

Comment: so I get what len(x) is referring to inside the lambda, but I though the second value was the accumulator. The result is correct, but what is len(y) doing inside the lambda?

Comment: For Python 3 `from functools import reduce` is needed.

Comment: @BrianHVB Got your point, I have modified my answer, But I would suggest this solution is just to help on your attempt, We have seen other simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned a `map` approach as well.  Here's one that works

```
x = [[4], [6, 4, 9], [4, 6], [0], []]

In [2]: sum(map(lambda x: len(x) if len(x) > 1 else 0, x))
Out[2]: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sum` with a generator expression isn't what I'd call functional style

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import add
>>> x = [[4], [6, 4, 9], [4, 6], [0], []]
>>> reduce(add, filter(1 .__lt__, map(len, x)))
5
```